# How to find a pattern with the specific file names in a nohup output?

Tags: linux, for-loop, grep, nohup

I ran a for loop with several commands over different files in shell under nohup. I need to get the log values of one of the commands which gets printed on the terminal (in this case, in the nohup.out file). I tried to do an **egrep** and find the pattern. Though, I got my log values, I do not know it belongs to which file. I want to print the file name along with the values. Is there a way to do so ? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

My nohup.out file looks like

```
100000 GFF lines processed.
200000 GFF lines processed.
300000 GFF lines processed.
400000 GFF lines processed.
500000 GFF lines processed.
600000 GFF lines processed.
700000 GFF lines processed.
.
.
.
about 10000 lines 
.
.
.
__no_feature    XXXX
__ambiguous 102723
__too_low_aQual 0
__not_aligned   0
.
.
.
.
```

This goes on for several different files. I want to extract the four lines which has "__no_feature" etc with their input file names.

I used egrep :

```
egrep "__no_feature|__ambiguous|__too_low_aQual|__not_aligned|__alignment_not_unique" nohup.out
```

But I got only the patterns and not the file names.

Comment: Please include your code and sample input/output so that the requirement is clear.

Comment: Hello Inquisitive8995, welcome to SO. In order for us to help you, please add more details on what you've tried. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to ask good questions.

Comment: Just edited my question. Hope it is better.

Answer (score 0):

*Try using egrep -H option*

```
egrep -H "__no_feature|__ambiguous|__too_low_aQual|__not_aligned|__alignment_not_unique" nohup.out
```

-H option is used view the file name along with the matched line
-h option is used o hide the filename from the matched line